# Access outer members in Javascript module

Tags: javascript, module, scope, closures

I have a module

```
something = {
    value : "",
    anotherVal : "",
    method : function(){
           this.anotherVal = "I think it is accessable here";
           GLOBAL.action(
           func : function(){
               // In here I want to access the above value.
               // Which is a property of the outer something module.
               <![magicOccursHere]!>.value = "magically access outer scope"
           });
    }
}
```

As you can see from the above code I would like to access a property on a level of scope outside of `this` by using some magicaOccursHere...

I have done this before by making the module return a function not a json object and then naming each level. But I dislike this syntax.

```
SOMETHING = new Something();
something = function Something() {
    var bigDaddy = this;
    this.value = "";
    this.anotherVal = "";
    this.method = function(){
           bigdaddy.anotherVal = "Set one of big daddies vars";
           GLOBAL.action(
           func : function(){
               // In here I want to access the above value.
               // Which is a property of the outer something module.
               bigdaddy.value = "can still set one of big daddies vars"
           });
    }
}
```

I may be completely missing the point here and if you would like to point me to it, then I would be only too happy to read.

Am I being too harsh on the messy pattern and code of option 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a local variable inside your `method` function, it will be in scope in the inner `func`:

```
var something = {
    value : "",
    anotherVal : "",
    method : function(){
           var obj = this;
           this.anotherVal = "I think it is accessable here";
           GLOBAL.action(
           func : function(){
               // In here I want to access the above value.
               // Which is a property of the outer something module.
               obj.anotherVal = "magically access outer scope"
           });
    }
}
```

Or you can use the fully qualified path:

```
var something = {
    value : "",
    anotherVal : "",
    method : function(){
           this.anotherVal = "I think it is accessable here";
           GLOBAL.action(
           func : function(){
               // In here I want to access the above value.
               // Which is a property of the outer something module.
               something.anotherVal = "magically access outer scope"
           });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's all so simple and obvious when you think about it. Thankyou very much.